# How does the default webpack config file looks like in angular-cli?

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

where can I find what all default webpack is capable of in angular-cli.

Ex.(ng build --prod builds the code in production mode) internally it minifies/uglifies the code. Can I view the code for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the options for `ng build` in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)